# Trying to estimate the temperature rise ΔT of an object, Q = mcΔT, BUT using a temperature dependent specific heat capacity c(T).

Tags: calculus, physics

Using $Q = mcΔT$ I can calculate the temperature rise in an object.

I apply $1\ J$, to a $1\ kg$ mass of water which has $c = 4184\ \frac{J}{kg * K}$ and I get about $.24\ mK$.

Well now I want to estimate the heat rise $ΔT$ of an object using a temperature dependent specific heat capacity $c(T) = -0.2065*T + 1058.74$ , and I don't think I can use $Q = mcΔT$ and I'm not sure what to do.

I can interpret this equation $Q = mcΔT$ as the heat rise $ΔT$ that corresponds to $Q$ heat applied to a mass with a fixed $c$.

I can also interpret this equation as the heat required to change a mass $m$ with $c$ by $ΔT$.

Initial Temperature = $293.15\ K$ btw.
I'm expecting about temperature rise of about $.24\ mK$, but I want to have a theoretical calculation.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to find $\Delta T$ for $Q= 1$ Joule ?

Comment: Yup! Got a result! (Myself too :D)

Comment: @WW1 What's odd is I get 293.15100179617, while I expected 293.15025 or so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the differential equation form when heat capacity is a function of temperature

Observe that $Q = mC\Delta T$ is the integrated form the differential equation of heat transfer when $C$ is a constant. The actual equation is

$$dQ = mCdT$$

Hence, to solve for the temperature difference, we have

$$\int dQ = m\int_{T_1}^{T_2} CdT$$
$$\implies 1 = 1\cdot\int_{293.15}^{T_2}(-0.2065T + 1058.74)dT$$

This gives a quadratic in $T_2$, out of which only one root should make physical sense

Comment: Yup! I figured it out. But oddly, I got Tf ≈ 293.1489982040342603 which is odd, because I expected a temperature rise from 293.15. Any idea why? Edit: Oh I messed up when I subtracted 1 from both sides. Thanks!

Comment: What's odd is I get 293.15100179617, while I expected 293.15025 or so. Any ideas?

Comment: Why were you expecting 0.25 mK? In the first case - with a $c$ of $4000$ you got $0.24 mK$ , whereas in the second case you have a $c$ of ~$1000$, which means your $\Delta T$ should be roughly 4x, hence around $1 mK$. This makes sense to me